# How to delete multiple or single rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent-child, removeclass, delete-row

I have tables with father son relationships. If you delete the father, the sons under it are deleted. You can also delete an individual son. My code so far doesn't delete the father or son with the corresponding id, it deletes the first thing in the table. 
**Here is my code:**

```
<script>
function delVesselAll(num){
    $("#vessel_tab #father" + num).remove();
    $("#vessel_tab .son" + num).remove();
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
};
function delSon(num){
    $("#vessel_tab #son" + num).remove();
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
};
</script>
```

**And my HTML:**

```
<table id="vessel_tab">
  <tr id="father1">
    <td colspan="2" class="father_header">Father 1</td>
    <td><a style="text-decoration:none;" onclick="showModal('delAllModal')"><input type="button" value="delete" onclick="showModal('delAllModal')"></a></td>
      <div class="delModal" style="z-index:999999; margin-left:200px; margin-top:10px; display:none" id="delAllModal">
Are you sure you want to delete the father and corresponding sons?<br /><input type="button" value="Cancel" class="hide" onclick="hideModal('delAllModal')"/><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="delVesselAll(1)" id="delete"/></div>
  </tr>
  <tr class="son1" id="son1">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Son 1</td>
    <td><a style="text-decoration:none;" onclick="showModal('delSonModal')"><input type="button" value="delete"></a></td>
      <div class="delModal" style="z-index:999999; margin-left:200px; margin-top:30px; display:none" id="delSonModal">
Please confirm deletion.<br /><input type="button" value="Cancel" class="hide" onclick="hideModal('delSonModal')"/><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="delSon(1)"/></div>
  </tr>
  <tr class="son2" id="son2">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Son 2</td>
    <td><a style="text-decoration:none;" onclick="showModal('delSonModal')"><input type="button" value="delete"></a></td>
      <div class="delModal" style="z-index:999999; margin-left:200px; margin-top:30px; display:none" id="delSonModal">
Please confirm deletion.<br /><input type="button" value="Cancel" class="hide" onclick="hideModal('delSonModal')"/><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="delSon(2)"/></div>
  </tr>
  <tr id="father2">
    <td colspan="2">Father 2</td>
    <td><a style="text-decoration:none;" onclick="showModal('delAllModal')"><input type="button" value="delete"></a></td>
      <div class="delModal" style="z-index:999999; margin-left:200px; margin-top:10px; display:none" id="delAllModal">
Are you sure you want to delete the father and corresponding sons?<br /><input type="button" value="Cancel" class="hide" onclick="hideModal('delAllModal')"/><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="delVesselAll(2)" id="delete"/></div>
  </tr>
 <tr class="son3" id="son3">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Son 3</td>
    <td><a style="text-decoration:none;" onclick="showModal('delSonModal')"><input type="button" value="delete"></a></td>
      <div class="delModal" style="z-index:999999; margin-left:200px; margin-top:30px; display:none" id="delSonModal">
Please confirm deletion.<br /><input type="button" value="Cancel" class="hide" onclick="hideModal('delSonModal')"/><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="delSon(3)"/></div>
  </tr>
  <tr class="son4" id="son4">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Son 4</td>
    <td><a style="text-decoration:none;" onclick="showModal('delSonModal')"><input type="button" value="delete"></a></td>
      <div class="delModal" style="z-index:999999; margin-left:200px; margin-top:30px; display:none" id="delSonModal">
Please confirm deletion.<br /><input type="button" value="Cancel" class="hide" onclick="hideModal('delSonModal')"/><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="delSon(4)"/></div>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Also, the jsfiddle. It's not working correctly(don't know what I did wrong), but my code is there. Thanks in advance!
http://jsfiddle.net/7tFFS/1/

Comment: The reason your fiddle isn't working is you need to change the dropdown in the upper right from onLoad to noWrap (head)

Comment: Updated! The deletes are not working correctly. Any idea?

Comment: It's because you are using an ID selector.. and have elements with the same `ID's` ..  IDs need to be unique or else you will always only get the first element with that id

Comment: The jsFiddle link is invalid.

Comment: @wirey my ids are son1, son2 and so on. Can you explain?

Comment: Yep.. `showModal('delSonModal')` code opens div modals.. which your div modals all have the same id `<div class="delModal" style="z-index:999999; margin-left:200px; margin-top:30px; display:none" id="delSonModal">`  So it will always only open the first element it finds.. I pm'd you

Comment: @wirey but the modals aren't the issue. They open, close fade in and out fine. My rows don't delete in order. onclick="delSon(2)" should delete the row with id="son2", right?

Comment: Nope that is the issue.. You're always opening the div modal which calls `delVesselAll(1)`.. because the that's the first div modal with that ID...  So that's why its always/only delete the first row

Comment: @wirey. You're right again. Fixed the problem. I think I may have had it that way before but there was a typo somewhere and I thought it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cleaned things up and refactored your code. Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UVwB7/6/).

The HTML:

```
<div class="delModal" style="z-index:999999; margin-left:200px; margin-top:10px; display:none"
id="delAllModal">Are you sure you want to delete the father and corresponding sons?
    <br
    />
    <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="hide" />
    <input type="button" value="Delete" class="delete" />
</div>
<div class="delModal" style="z-index:999999; margin-left:200px; margin-top:30px; display:none"
id="delSonModal">Please confirm deletion.
    <br />
    <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="hide" />
    <input type="button" value="Delete" class="delete" />
</div>
<table id="vessel_tab">
    <tr id="father1">
        <td colspan="2" class="father_header">Father 1</td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="delete" class="delete" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="son1" id="son1" data-father="father1">
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Son 1</td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="delete" class="delete" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="son2" id="son2" data-father="father1">
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Son 2</td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="delete" class="delete" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="father2">
        <td colspan="2">Father 2</td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="delete" class="delete" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="son3" id="son3" data-father="father2">
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Son 3</td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="delete" class="delete" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="son4" id="son4" data-father="father2">
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Son 4</td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="delete" class="delete" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The JS:

```
function showModal(id, child) {
    var $modal = $(child ? "#delSonModal" : "#delAllModal");
    $modal.fadeIn("slow")
        .find(".delete")
        .one("click", function () {
            $("#" + id + ", [data-father=" + id + "]").fadeOut("slow");
            $modal.fadeOut("slow");
        });
}


$("input.hide").click(function () {
    $(this).closest("div.delModal").fadeOut("slow");
});

$("#vessel_tab input.delete").bind("click", function () {
    var $tr = $(this).closest("tr");
    showModal($tr.attr("id"), !!$tr.data("father"));
});
```

**EDIT**:

Your Fiddle wasn't working because of your use of in-HTML onClick handlers. It's not necessarily wrong, but JSFiddle didn't seem to like it. I replaced those with jQuery handlers, throughout.

In the HTML, your repeating of your dialogs wasn't necessary so I took those out and put them outside the table. There were some anchor tags that were superfluous as well, which I removed. I also added slashes to the end of your input tags... Not really all that necessary, but XHTML requires it and it made Fiddle crazy, so that's that. I used classes instead of ID's in some places (like the cancel/delete buttons) to give a simple way to reference them in jQuery as a group. (You can't have duplicate ID tags without things throwing up.) The `data-father` tag on all the sons is what is used later in `showModal` to determine which dialog (`delAllModal` or `delSonModal`) should be displayed, and more importantly to link the sons to their fathers to allow their deletion as a whole unit.

In the JS:

- A lot of the code I rewrote to just execute in-line instead of calling a function. The exception being `showModal`.
- `$("input.hide").click...` Wires up both of the Cancel buttons in the dialogs.
- `$("#vessel_tab input.delete")...` Wires up all of the Delete buttons *in the table*. It's basically just a wrapper for `showModal`...
- ...which brings us to the meat. `showModal`:

  - The `var $modal...` line picks which dialog to display based on if the clicked button was for a child.
  - The dialog is shown, and its delete button is wired up. Notice that I use `one` here, and not `on`. This will make a click handler for the button, but dispose of it immediately upon it's use. `on` would have probably worked fine, but this leaves less mess behind.
  - The click handler calls `fadeOut` on both the passed ID, and any elements that have that have that ID as their `data-father` attribute - effectively, ID's children. For Fathers, this hides the Father and the Sons. For Sons it only hides the Son since no elements will have `data-father` attributes matching the Son's ID.
  - Finally, we close the dialog.

I hope this is all pretty clear. Happy Hacking!

Comment: Beautiful, and more than I asked for! I like that the deleted rows fade out as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the structure of html little bit.

Why dont you add sons to be contained under father element.
For example:

```
<tr id="father_1">
  <td class="father_1">Father 1</td>
  <td class="son_of_f1" id="son_1">Son 1</td>
  <td class="son_of_f1" id="son_2">Son 2</td>
  <td class="son_of_f1" id="son_3">Son 3</td>
  <td class="son_of_f1" id="son_4">Son 4</td>
</tr>
```

Then you can do following with JQuery

```
 $('#father_1').fadeOut(500);
 $('.son_of_f1').fadeOut(500);`
```

and you can make `_1` to be dynamic and save it into variable

NOTE: using classes rather than IDS for each son is better since you cant have two sons have the same id.

Comment: according to this [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/td) documentation.. the only permitted parent is a `<tr>`

Comment: I don't have the option to change the son rows to table data under the father.

Comment: then change the classes of sons not to increment just make them same that correspond to the father like son_of_f1 and you do not have to hardcode 1 at the end, can make it dynamic, it will make easy to access father's sons.